# How can I convert string to time in Powershell 2.0?

Tags: powershell-2.0

So I was trying to compare some log entries (string) in the format of "mm:ss", my question is how can I cast/convert the  strings to datetime so that I can compare them? For example, how can I convert string "00:00" to 0 seconds?

FYI, the log looks like:

```
04-04-2018 15:59:17 Elapse time 00:16
```

And I was able to pull the elapse time by using

```
foreach {
  $fContent = $_ -split 'Elapse time'
  $fContent[1]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some research, I was able to achieve the goal by using the following code:

```
$i = [Datetime]::ParseExact($data, "mm:ss", $null)
$j= [Datetime]::Today

$result = $i-$j

$flag = $result.TotalSeconds

$flag
```

issue resolved. Thanks